# How to add border-radius to the marker pop

Tags: highcharts

If you look at the example [here](http://jsfiddle.net/gh/get/jquery/1.7.2/highslide-software/highcharts.com/tree/master/samples/highcharts/plotoptions/series-marker-states-hover-radius/); when hovering the mouse over a marker point a rectangular box pops up. How do I provide a border-radius to this box.

[image]

```
series: {
                marker: {
                    lineColor: null,
                    states: {
                        hover: {
                            fillColor: 'white',
                            radius: 10
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can change border radius via `tooltip.borderRadius` property.

```
tooltip: {
        borderRadius: 20
    },
```

example: http://jsfiddle.net/L24w2ghd/